# how to read configuration setting in simple HTML file?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a simple HTML page in my ASP.net web application. is there any way to read the configuration setting from HTML page with out converting it in aspx page?

Comment: Define simple :).. you could use AJAX request in your HTML to retrieve the info from the server and then inject it to your DOM using javascript.. but i guess it is not as simple as you would like it to be . :)

Comment: It you want to read configuration, it is not a static html file. Why not convert it to a page? You can redirect the html url to that page.